# Openpyxl: Removing Duplicate cells from a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to remove the duplicate entries from a column using openpyxl and writing the unique entries to a different workbook.

Input File:

```
Cust1
Cust1
Cust1
Cust2
Cust2
Cust3
```

Expected Output is:

```
Cust1
Cust2
Cust3
```

```
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('OldFile.xlsx')
ws = wb1.active
wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
k=1
new_row1 = []
for i in range(2, ws.max_row + 1 ):
  new_row1.append([])                   #list for storing the unique entries
  row_name = ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value  #taking the 1st cell's value
  new_row1[k].append(row_name)              #Appending the list
  ws2.append(new_row1)                      #writing to new workbook
  k+=1                                     
  for j in range(3, ws.max_row + 1 ):
    row_name2 = ws.cell(row=j, column=1).value #taking 2nd cell's value
    if row_name == row_name2:                  #comparing both the values
      i+=1                                      
      j+=1
wb2.save('NewFile.xlsx')
```

I am getting `"IndexError: list index out of range" for line "new_row1[k].append(row_name)"`, also apart from the mentioned error is there something that has to be changed to get the required output.

Comment: You need `k = 0` instead of `k = 1`. Lists in Python start with index 0. Use the `set()` function to make a list of data unique in Python. Your question is not an Excel question but a 100% Python question.

Comment: Please spend some time familiarising yourself with the openpyxl documentation. This is unnecessarily complicated code. Break it down into chunks that are easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @CharlieClark said your code is overly complicated. Try instead:

```
ws1 = wb1.active # keep naming convention consistent

values = []
for i in range(2,ws1.max_row+1):
  if ws1.cell(row=i,column=1).value in values:
    pass # if already in list do nothing
  else:
    values.append(ws1.cell(row=i,column=1).value)

for value in values:
  ws2.append([value])
```

Comment: assign `values = set()` for duplication check efficiency

Comment: @mechanical_meat for what did you use the last 2 code lines? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

iter_rows can be use

```
ws1 = wb1.active   

values = []
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    if row[1].value in values:
        pass
    else:
        values.append(row[1].value)

for value in values:
  ws2.append([value])
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested ok solution:

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('old_file.xlsx')
wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook('new_file.xlsx')
sh=wb['Sheet1']
sh2=wb2['Sheet1']

values= []

for i in range(1,sh.max_row+1):
    a=sh.cell(row=i,column=1).value
    if a in values:
        pass
    else:   
        values.append(sh.cell(row=i,column=1).value)

for x in range(len(values)): 
    sh2.cell(row=x+1,column=1).value=values[x]

wb2.save('new_file.xlsx')
```